# Aggravated Rebus Puzzling

Tags: visual, rebus

### Hullo, what's all this then?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Clicking enlarges the pictures, but isn't required for solving the puzzles; Imgur's automatic cropping managed to keep the essential bits in the smaller pictures too. The bigger images may have a better resolution though.)

---

Hint for puzzle 6:

> Apart from 6, everything as already been solved, so here's a hint:
>
>  The answer to 6 is an older one, and no longer belongs with the rest of the answers in many places. Also, if you live in the US, you may be used to a longer name for the first part.

Second hint for puzzle 6:

> Since reading the music in a European way is a bit difficult, you can also search wikipedia for more clues.

Comment: Is each image a separate puzzle/rebus or do they all form one larger one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Image 1:

> Manslaughter - Man's laughter

Image 2:

> Bigamy - Big Amy

3:

> Kidnap - Kid (baby goat) napping

4:

> Rape - Per @Greg

5:

> Pickpocket

6:

> I feel like it has to end in -ancy (in C) or end in c sound.  Heresy - Hear a C.

7:

> Blackmail ? - Black chain mail?

Which all:

> happen to fit the theme of crimes (the title is a clue for this as well)

Comment: 6 needs some more musical insight, otherwise you are spot on.

Comment: is # 6 rot13(Znwbe fpber)? (or just the last word by itself)

Comment: could #6 be rot13(gevnq)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_inversion

Answer (score 5):

Partial:

Newer:

> Considering the title is aggravated, and the topic is crime as all have pointed out, had I a link to an image of an angry donkey covered in salt, this would be the time I'd use it.

Image 6:
wild shot but

> Misdemeanor (Missed A minor)?

---

Image 5:

> Pickpocket

Image 6:

> <s>A cropped image that says "C major 2nd inversion". So either the C is unimportant, or the C is everything. If it is, might lean towards a homophone like see or sea.</s>
>  clicking on the image actually shows the C. Derp. I didn't think to try when I read the "clicking to enlarge won't matter" part haha.

Comment: All the images are cropped somewhat. OP says enlarging them isn't necessary, so if you don't, how will you know it is cropped?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly, but I ended up googling "major second inversion" and came across the exact same image in full. After doing so, I came back and clicked on the image here and found that it was not actually cropped like I thought when comparing the small image vs what I had googled.

Comment: Just saying... if OP says expanding the images is unnecessary, then surely any further detail they contain is unnecessary.

Comment: Ahh. Then yes, by that logic, my current thought on image 6 is essentially moot.

Comment: Your image 6 is much better than mine!

Comment: Your newer one is my favorite so far

Answer (score 5):

## Partial

Image 4:

> Rape - the flower is [rapeseed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapeseed)

Comment: Nice! I never would have found that

Comment: @JGibbers to be fair, I'm really, really good at googling!

Answer (score 3):

The musical notes in #6 are

> "sol do mi" or "so do mi" in [solfège](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge)

So the answer could be

> **Sodomy**, which used to be a [serious crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodomy_law) in the west and still is in many places.

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

One unsolved

> crime

remains in Image 6. Here are several suggestions

> **Racket**
>  It's a bit thin, but some consider music to be a racket (noise), and a racket
>  operation is a crime.
>  
>  **Corruption**
>  Because the harmony is a corruption of C major.
>  
>  **Inversion**
>  Because the word is there in the image and is the name of a "crime" in the
>  late 19th and early 20th century. From the hint added to the question the
>  fuller name is **sexual inversion**.